# How to properly use this code?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, shutdown

I'm trying to get this code to work. I want this batch file to disable the shutdown button for the current user. How would this work? Like what would I substitute in the SID:D section? Here is the script I have so far:

**The Main Code**: icacls %windir%\system32\shutdown.exe /deny %SI%:D

The Script

```
:setup
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >null
rename %windir%\System32\shutdown.exe shutdown1stop.exe >null
echo.
wmic useraccount where name='%username%' get SID
echo.
echo COPY THE CODE ABOVE DOWN...
echo.
echo Press any key to continue.
pause >null
goto ctnustp

:ctnustp
cls
echo Configuring Settings...
timeout /t 3 /nobreak >null
echo Enter the code you copied down earlier:
set /p SI=
icacls %windir%\system32\shutdown.exe /deny %SI%:D
echo Configuration Successful.
echo Press any key to continue.
pause >null
```

Comment: You're renaming the file at the top, but then trying to set ACLs on it towards the bottom.  Assuming the rename is successful, the file is gone, icacls won't be able to change permission to it.  And even if it did, you're telling it to deny permission to delete the executable; that won't stop them running it.

Also, I thought this was for the "shutdown.exe" command line program only; I don't think this would disable the button on the start menu.  The only way I know to do that is through GPO or Local Security Policy; I haven't been able to find a command-line way to do it yet...

Comment: could you, if you find it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657)

```
NTRIGHTS –r SeShutdownPrivilege –u "<User or Group>"
```

[How To Disable/Remove Shutdown From Windows 7 / Vista / XP](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-disable-remove-shutdown-from-windows-xp-and-vista/) cmd:

```
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" /v NoClose /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" /v NoClose /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System /v DisableCMD /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

but, it bad way, see `tsshutdn`

Comment: What wwould i put and where would i put it? Thank you somuch

Comment: @AreebAshar http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779329(v=ws.10).aspx as sample

Comment: Im trying to do this: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-disable-remove-shutdown-from-windows-xp-and-vista/                                                         .                                                                                    but i want to do it using a batch file. How?

Comment: @AreebAshar Update